# How can I set app as default on Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Good day, i want to set my application default for a file type with coocoa framework. Now i write next code:

```
bool setappasdefualt()
{
    OSStatus returnStatus = LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType(CFSTR(".txt"), kLSRolesAll, (CFStringRef) [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
    if (returnStatus != 0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Got an error when setting default application - %ld", returnStatus);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but after execution it get error 50. What i do wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"`.txt`" is a file extension, not a uniform type identifier (UTI).

You need to use a proper UTI, e.g. `CFSTR("public.plain-text")`

User Guillaume wrote a nice little function to convert file extensions to UTI's, [you can see it here, named "`UTIforFileExtension:`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8645445/272342) (and you should upvote his answer if it helps you :-)